How to receive an email for failed SMS deliveries on AWS SNS
I use AWS SNS to send one-time passwords. Last week I reached quota, the server stopped sending messages and users have been unable to log in. I set up CloudWatch to receive a notification on failed deliveries. This page gives directions on how to set up a daily summary of SMS statistics on S3, but I would like to receive an email for each failed SMS delivery (not for both successful and failed deliveries) and ideally not going through S3.
Is that possible?
